# Inspect docker stack via ansible

Tags: ansible, docker-swarm

I want to use ansible to know whether a docker stack is deployed. In the shell I'd do something like: `docker stack services -q my_stack_name`.

I could use the `shell` module, but then I have to manually handle errors and idempotence.

Is there a module for this? (I looked over the docs of `docker_swarm_info` but it isn't appropriate.)

Comment: Are scripted local facts at all an option for you?

Comment: @FelixFrank I just perform the work using the `shell` module, and it works. But it would be nice if there were an official approach that is less brittle. Maybe `shell` is the only option for now.

Comment: okay but that does not answer my question ;) I'll just build an answer, you can see if it applies to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a [local fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) that provides this information.

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/ansible/facts.d/docker_stack
echo "{\"info\": \"`docker stack services -q my_stack_name`\"}"
```

In your playbook, you can then use the `ansible_local.docker_stack.info` variable.

(Of course, it will likely more effective to make this a Python script that returns structured JSON data rather than a fugly, possibly multi-line string.)

Do note that this will not notice any changes that happen during a playbook run.

Comment: Another good workaround, thanks.